# Are turbine engine reconditioned after severe FOD damage caused by bird strikes?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine

I've just been watching a video of a 757 suffering a bird strike on take off. The pilots continue with their take off, declare a MAYDAY, shut the engine down and proceed to land without any issues.

Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KhZwsYtNDE

Are these engine reused after an event like this? Are they sent away to Rolls Royce, Pratt & Whitney etc to be repaired? Or are they always deemed a complete write off and replaced with new?

Obviously turbine engines are highly balanced complex pieces of machinery so I can imagine once FOD has damaged this balancing the damage is pretty high.

Comment: I'd like to see this video ;)

Comment: @ShaanSingh I've added a link to the video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The damage is assessed and then a determination is made whether or not its economical to repair the engine.  It will truly be taken on a case by case basis.  However, FOD damage to the engine doesn't automatically mean the engine will be scrapped, and I think you'd be surprised with the damage they can suffer and still remain in service after repair.

Answer (score 1):

Repair and replacement of engine components are performed in accordance with the manufacturer's specifications.  Economic evaluations may be used to determine whether the engine can be serviced in the field, in a service depot (third party or engine manufacturer based), re-built, re-manufactured or scrapped.

In cases where a plane I have flown has ingested FOD (birds, stones, etc.) the first step is normally for the company mechanic to utilize a bore scope for a visual inspection.  In the case of the PT6 engine families, I have observed that no damage is normally found and the engine returns to service.  Obviously that is situational.